# How can I differentiate small and big letters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have query to find out the duplicates in my data but that query also encountering the data which  are not duplicates but my query sees it as a duplicate because my query reading them same. For example 'AABWcFABmAAAyWJAAb' and 'AABWcFABmAAAyWJAAB' but in actual they are unique since this both id holds different data. I have used Collate function but it didn't help. Please let me know if there is any built in function I can use or any logic.
Thank you in advance for the help.

```
select distinct 
    npa
    ,npanxx_row_id
    ,count()
from kjm.audit_309 
where npanxx_row_id 
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS in (npanxx_row_id) --and NPANXX_ROW_ID = 'AABWcFABmAAAyWJAAB' 
group by npa,npanxx_row_id 
having count() >1 
order by npa
```

Comment: Querying with the correct collation is the answer. Please post the query you are using to find duplicates now, together with the table definition

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Michael I am using:

select distinct npa, npanxx_row_id, count(*)
from kjm.audit_309
where npanxx_row_id COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS in (npanxx_row_id) --and NPANXX_ROW_ID = 'AABWcFABmAAAyWJAAB'
group by npa,npanxx_row_id
having count(*) >1
order by npa

Comment: @Mr.Jin, Rather than posting code in comments, edit your answer to include it.  I've done that for you this time.

Comment: @Dan I am using ssrs

Comment: You need the `COLLATE` in the `GROUP BY`, otherwise it's still grouping by the non-case sensitive value.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Whatever "ssrs" is, it's not a (popular) DBMS.

Comment: If you received an answer from this post, please mark the answer accordingly and give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option in SQL Server would potentially be BINARY_CHECKSUM().  This will detect differences in case.

```
select 

your_column
, BINARY_CHECKSUM(your_column)
, COUNT(*)

FROM your_table

GROUP BY 
your_column
, BINARY_CHECKSUM(your_column)

HAVING count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for duplicates, then this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #case_sensitivity_training (my_str VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #case_sensitivity_training (my_str)
VALUES ('AABWcFABmAAAyWJAAb'), ('AABWcFABmAAAyWJAAB')

SELECT
    my_str COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    #case_sensitivity_training
GROUP BY
    my_str COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put the collation in the wrong spot if you want to use `DISTINCT`.

The following should work on SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (ColumnName) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as 
From TableName
```

But that collation may vary from RDBMS to RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you for your help too.